# Python Azure Function failing with AttributeError('__enter__') after updating Azure Core Tools

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, pymysql, azure-functions-core-tools

I have a Azure Function Python script. It has a http trigger and connects to a MySQL DB and gets the rows from a table and processes it. I use VS Code to develop it and test it using the Python vEnv. (aka pressing F5 to run it locally)

It used to work perfectly for a long time but a week ago I updated my VS Code and the Azure core tools, did some minor changes, deployed and now it doesn't work, when running in Azure it throws some cryptic error `AttributeError('__enter__')`. So I went back to VS Code, run it in the vEnv and it works just fine there. So the issue only happens when running on Azure Functions.

Google did not help much I managed to find that it might relate to the `with` part for `pymysql`. I did some debugging with logging right before and after the `with` block and it does seem to fail exactly there. But I'm stuck and not sure how to debug any further.

It is not related to the code change that I did, I am convinced that something happened when I updated the VS Code Azure Functions runtime or something in Azure itself has changed.

I have installed `Python 3.8.2 64-bit vEnv` and the Azure core tools version `3.0.2630`

Here is the seemingly relevant part of the code:

```
def getDbData(connection,table):
    with connection: 
        cur = connection.cursor()
        cur.execute(f"SELECT * FROM {table}")
        rows = cur.fetchall()

    if len(rows) > 0:
        logging.info(f'Got {len(rows)} entries from {table} SQL table!')
        connection.commit()
        for row in rows:
            logging.info(f'do something with each row')
    else:
        logging.info(f'Did not get any results from {table} SQL table!')
        connection.commit()


connection = pymysql.connect(host='hostname',user='SA',password='Passw',db='database',charset='utf8',use_unicode=True,cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

dbindex = getDbData(connection,"dbTable")
```

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31214658/can-i-use-pymysql-connect-with-with-statement