# The proper way to ensure Python(Flask) closes DB connection (pymysql) on error

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-restful

The below is my way of handling database connection, but it is a bit clumsy than I want...So the question is whether or not there are some other even more proper ways to close the database while returning an error message to client if DB operations return some errors.

```
@app.route('/get-data/', methods=['GET'])
def get_data():

    db_error = False
    try:
        conn = pymysql.connect(db_url, db_username, db_password, db_name)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('SELECT a_column FROM a_table WHERE a_condition = 0')
        results = cursor.fetchall()
    except Exception as ex:
        logging.error('{ex}')
        db_error = True # Cannot simply return here; otherwise DB connection is left open
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()    

    if db_error:
        return Response('Database error', 500)
    return jsonify(results) # Let's assume the jsonify() function will not throw an error...
```

Suppose I use a context manager, does it mean that both `conn` and `cursor` will definitely be closed even when an exception is thrown? Or is it something implementation-dependent, i.e., some packages, say, `pymysql`, will make sure all `cursor`s and `conn`s are closed, regardless of errors are thrown or not; while other packages, say, `pyodbc`, will NOT ensure this. (Here `pymysql` and `pyodbc` are just two examples of course...)

Comment: Presumably you could use a context manager.

Comment: Hi @mkrieger1, do you mean that, say I used a context manager, both conn and cursor will definitely be automatically close when an exception is thrown?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use pymysql.connect() with "with" statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31214658/can-i-use-pymysql-connect-with-with-statement)

Comment: well @mkrieger1 I think the link partially says that what you just proposed (using context manager) will not solve my initial question. Please dont mark my question as duplicate because of this link.

Comment: `Cannot simply return here; otherwise DB connection is left open` - This comment is wrong, the `finally` part is executed in any case.

Comment: @mkrieger1 yes you are right. Then I think putting `close()` inside `finally` should be the right way to go.